# Devo usar tableview, collectionview ou scrollview quando trato de itens verticais diferentes um do outro no XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, osx, uitableview

Boa noite,

Comecei a aprender Swift a pouco tempo e estou tentando desenvolver um app no XCode. Hoje encontrei a seguinte situação: eu preciso fazer uma lista de informações na qual é possível dar scroll para baixo, além de poder expandir verticalmente uma das linhas da lista, mandando as outras para baixo, então pensei: "Ah, uma tableview, obviamente...".

Porém, o que acontece é que todas as células dessa tableview serão totalmente diferentes uma das outras, tanto em conteúdo quanto na posição dos elementos dentro da célula. E levando em conta todos os exemplos de tableviews que vi até hoje, parece que eles são sempre utilizados para listas padronizadas, como a lista de vídeos buscados no app do youtube, por exemplo. Comecei a fazer por tableview e me parece que estou fazendo muito código atoa, que deve ter uma forma mais fácil de fazer esse tipo de coisa.

Aí, descobri que existem dois potenciais meios de fazer o que eu quero: collection views e scroll views, que na minha ignorância parecem ter um foco menor em listas padronizadas.

Então, o que quero saber é: qual dessas 3 soluções é mais adequada para o meu caso, principalmente levando em consideração a facilidade e a flexibilidade delas para tratar com listas não padronizadas? Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Collection não resolveria o teu problema, já que ela tem a mesma usabilidade, a diferença entre ela e uma TableView basicamente é que, além de poder ter o scroll horizontal, ela pode conter colunas.
 A table view pode ter a sua altura modificada para se adaptar a todos tipos de conteúdos que precisar usando células dinâmicas e sua altura sendo imposta pelo uso de constraints, onde seu código ficará menos acoplado, criando uma classe para cada tipo de célula.
 E em ultimo caso, você pode usar uma ScrollView, porém seu uso é limitado em relação ao uma TableView, mas você pode estruturar o conteúdo de forma totalmente aleatória.
 Além disso outra diferença que você precisa se preocupar é com funcionalidades que uma table tem que uma scrollview não vai oferecer, como seleção, deleção de linha, entre outras funcionalidades de cada célula.

Uso da TableView com células dinâmicas

[image: TableView com células dinamicas]

Uso da CollectionView com 2 colunas 
[image: ColectionView com 2 colunas]

O arquivo do exemplo está neste [GitHub](https://github.com/Crowlleey/ExemploTableCollection)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta bem detalhada! Acabei usando uma tableview mesmo, resolveu bem e não era tão complicado como eu achava. Vou dar uma olhada nesse arquivo.

Comment: ATT: Aproveitei o projeto e estou implementando mais algumas coisas mas a  ideia continua a mesma